# Android Database SQLite Average

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am making an app for android with a SQLite Database that have only one table and two columns: one for names and the other for marks. Also, I can see the information of the database in a listview and I can add more elements to it. How can I make the average of the marks which are in the database? And how can I delete a row?

I paste my database helper

public class PersonDatabaseHelper {

```
private static final String TAG = PersonDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

// database configuration
// if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

// table configuration
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN = "person_pin";

private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

// this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
// but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations
public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

    openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonPin) {

    // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN, aPersonPin);

    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public Cursor getAllData () {

    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}

// this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation

private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
        super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Create your tables here

        String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN + " TEXT )";

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Database schema upgrade code goes here

        String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the avarage ([avg](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)) aggregate function:

```
String query = "SELECT AVG("+PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN +") FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
```

and then use [SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) for executing the query. Something like:

```
database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f838d/30) you can find a sample fiddle.

While, for deleting a row, you can use [SQLiteDatabase.delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])). For example:

```
String where = PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID+"=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(59)};
database.delete(TABLE_NAME, where, whereArgs);
```

the above code delete the row with id 59.

Comment: or.... `database.execSQL("DELETE " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN  + " WHERE " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " = ?";`

Comment: Yes, you can also use `execSQL()`, but I prefer to use `delete()`, since it is more structured and cleaner, and also, it returns the number of affected rows, which can be useful in many cases.

Comment: I prefer `execSQL()`, because you use the SQL commands directly. For the same reason I also prefer `rawQuery()` to `query()` (you can **easily** make **complex** queries).

Comment: Yes, but you can't know the number of rows affected by your `delete`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't care.

Comment: yes, in many cases it is not so important, but (IMHO) in many other situations it can be important :)

Comment: In those (for me **extremely rare**) situations, I'd do a counter SELECT to query how many rows are there with the required specs. :)

Comment: Thank you for the responses, but where I have to put the query? in the databasehelper on in the mainactivity? and how can i show the average as a textview? I'm a beginner

Comment: You are welcome. Use `DbHelper` (that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`) for getting the `SQLiteDatabase` instance (using the methos method `DbHelper.getWritableDatabase()` ) and then call `delete()` on it. For show a text in a `TextView` use the method [TextView.setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Yes, I know this, but how can i show the string query in a textview if the query is in the database helper and the textview is in the mainactivity?

Comment: @DerGol...lum Talking about  `execSQL()` the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) says " Instead, you're encouraged to use `insert(String, String, ContentValues)`, `update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])`, et al, when possible.".
@Alex you need to call you db helper from your activity.

Comment: Yes, but I'm encouraged **by myself** to think with **my head**. And I do prefer a lot  **direct SQL statements**. My tastes. That's it.

Comment: Follow the advices of those who have created Android does not mean not to think for themselves. However the advantages of insert, update, etc, are evident:
1. They return the number of affected rows.
2. Which one do you think is more readable and/or error prone? `db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null,null);` or `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME)`

Comment: **1** - I don't care for returned row counts. **2** -  This is surely more readable: `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME)`. For me, at least. Not even to mention **complex** queries (i.e.: select from 7 joined tables with likes)

Comment: @Joseph82 how can I call the db helper from my mainactivity?